# Grab specific string from exsiting data and put it in new column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a huge table like this:

```
DATA                                NUM             CITY               
----------------------------------- --------------- --------------------
ABC140180B                          51368           Hong Kong
ABC140180                           98563           New York
CENTER ABC140180                    65125           Philadephia
ABC230142                           48101           PARK          
SOUTHFIELD ABC230142                48083           Tokyo
GENERAL SURGERY ABC230053LJ         45896           Philadephia
CARDIOVASCULAR MEDICINE ABC230053LK 48192           Philadephia
GYNECOLOGIC ABC230053LL             25874           Philadephia
NEUROSURGERY ABC230053LC            48192           Tokyo
HENRY ABC230053FG                   11524           Tokyo
UROGYNECOLOGY ABC230053FH           62531           Tokyo
```

Is there any way I can Grab all string with "ABCXXXXXXX" from data and create a new table with one new column contain the data like:

```
DATA                                NUM             CITY                 DSH
----------------------------------- --------------- -------------------- -----------------
ABC140180B                          51368           Hong Kong            ABC140180B                          
ABC140180                           98563           New York             ABC140180                                     
CENTER ABC140180                    65125           Philadephia          ABC140180  
ABC230142                           48101           PARK                 ABC230142                                   
SOUTHFIELD ABC230142                48083           Tokyo                ABC230142  
GENERAL SURGERY ABC230053LJ         45896           Philadephia          ABC230053LJ         
CARDIOVASCULAR MEDICINE ABC230053LK 48192           Philadephia          ABC230053LK
GYNECOLOGIC ABC230053LL             25874           Philadephia          ABC230053LL
NEUROSURGERY ABC230053LC            48192           Tokyo                ABC230053LC
HENRY ABC230053FG                   11524           Tokyo                ABC230053FG
UROGYNECOLOGY ABC230053FH           62531           Tokyo                ABC230053FH
```

Can anyone help me please

Thanks in advance

Comment: Haha what the heck do you mean by "crap"??

Comment: @roryap Probably crop:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the examples you have given, you want the last "token" in string after the last space.

Oracle provides `regexp_substr()`:

```
select . . ., regexp_substr(' ' || data, ' [^ ]*$', 1, 1) as dsh
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done with `substr()` and `instr()` :

```
select t.*,
       substr(t.YourColumn, instr(t.YourColumn, 'ABC') + 1)  as DSH
from YourTable t;
```

This will take every char from `ABC` and forwards